# Broken pipe using "echo" command on a file descriptor holding a TCP connection

Tags: bash, sockets, file-descriptor, io-redirection

After reading article https://www.xmodulo.com/tcp-udp-socket-bash-shell.html, I tried to write a simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3<>/dev/tcp/time.nist.gov/13

for i in {1..3}; do
    echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: service\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n" >&3
    cat <&3
    echo "get sent"
    sleep 10
done
exec 3<&-
echo "done"
```

It successfully returned me the time but then only "Bad file descriptor".

But if I move the opening and the opening of file descriptor 3, it runs fine

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..3}; do
    exec 3<>/dev/tcp/time.nist.gov/13
    echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: service\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n" >&3
    cat <&3
    echo "get sent"
    exec 3<&-
    sleep 10
done

echo "done"
```

Why is that?

(I'd prefer to keep the TCP socket open without closing and re-opening it.)

Comment: You tell the server to close the connection header: `Connection: close`.

Comment: Hint: I would use: `printf 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: service\r\n\r\n' | ncat time.nist.gov 13` for a one time shoot.

Comment: I tested ncat command of above 3 times with sleep 10, and the server disconnects after some seconds.

Comment: @Wiimm Removing that doesn't make a difference, but it's not clear the NIST servers keep the connection open anyway. Users are encouraged *not* to use these, but to use NTP instead.

Comment: use `while read -t .02 -u 3 line;do echo $line;done`  instead of `cat <&3`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 13 is the daytime protocol, which is not HTTP. Thus sending a HTTP request to the server is wrong in the first place. Instead one must follow the specification of the daytime protocol - see [Wikipedia: Daytime Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daytime_Protocol) for an overview.

Basically the protocol works by doing a connect to the server and reading until connection close - the client does not send any application data at all. Since one must read until connection close and there is no concept of a "request" one also cannot keep the connection open for more "requests". Instead a new connection must be created for each new query.

```
for i in {1..3}; do
    exec 3<>/dev/tcp/time.nist.gov/13
    cat <&3
    exec 3<&-
    sleep 10
done
echo "done"
```

But even if the other side would be an HTTP server the tried approach will not work. For one: the HTTP request explicitly asks for `Connection: close`, thus excluding multiple requests on the same connection. And, the `cat <&3` reads until connection close by the server instead of HTTP response end, which makes getting multiple responses on the same connection and thus also multiple requests impossible too.